# AWS CDK providing incorrect definitions for Jest testing on object properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I've created an S3 bucket using the AWS CDK like so

```js
new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyFirstBucket', {
      versioned: true,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS,
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
    });
```

But I'm not having much success writing Jest tests for it. I've tried to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html#Capturing but not really having anyluck. The `s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL` returns
`{"blockPublicAccess": {"blockPublicAcls": true, "blockPublicPolicy": true, "ignorePublicAcls": true, "restrictPublicBuckets": true}}`

but when I try to compare this in my tests the object is comprised of

`..."PublicAccessBlockConfiguration": {"BlockPublicAcls": true, "BlockPublicPolicy": true, "IgnorePublicAcls": true, "RestrictPublicBuckets": true}...`

I've managed to pass tests but only by copying content from the CDK.out json file, however I feel this is counterintuitive to how tests should be written. Below is my Test code, Any help would be much appreciated.

````js
  expect(template).toHaveProperty("AWS::S3::Bucket", {
        blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL
    }) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The [fine-grain assertions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html) *"test specific aspects of the generated AWS CloudFormation template"*. Templates have `PascalCase` property keys.  So we can't assert against the `camelCase` keys in the Typescript CDK classes.

Not a problem! Simply convert the `camelCase` to `PascalCase`:

```js
const blockAllAccess = s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL as unknown as Record<string, string>;

const blockAllAccessPascal = Object.entries(blockAllAccess).reduce(
  (acc, [k, v]) => {
    acc[k[0].toUpperCase() + k.substring(1)] = v;
    return acc;
  }, {});

expect(bucketStack).toHaveResourceLike('AWS::S3::Bucket', {
  PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: blockAllAccessPascal,
});
```